# how to let wc command recursivly?

Tags: linux

Let it counting  *.h *.cpp  in Sub directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you want it seperate per file:

```
find -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec wc {} \;
```

if you want the accumulated sum:

```
find -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
wc **/*.{cpp,h}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `find` and `xargs` is clearer and easier to work with instead of `find -exec` but it's style choice.

`find . -name "*.h" -or -name "*.cpp" | xargs wc`

Answer (score 0):

Use zsh instead of bash:

```
wc **/*.(cpp|h)
```

This will expand out to all the .cpp and .h files in the current directory and all subdirectories.